# Subquery returns more than 1 row| Is it possible to use "AND NOT IN"?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT r.rom_ID
    FROM rom r
    WHERE r.rom_ID NOT LIKE(

    SELECT r.rom_ID
    FROM rom r, booking b 
    WHERE b.rom_ID = r.rom_ID 
    and (
         '2018-05-08' BETWEEN b.ankomstdato AND b.utsjekkdato OR
             '2018-05-12' BETWEEN b.ankomstdato AND b.utsjekkdato OR 
             ('2018-05-08' <= b.ankomstdato AND  '2018-05-12' >= b.utsjekkdato
        ) ) )  AND r.romtype_ID = 2
        LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: First, you cannot use `LIKE` like that. Second, why don't you use joins instead of a subquery?

Comment: use (not in ) instead of (not like)

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Also, you should probably ask another question, with sample data and desired results.  Your query as written does not seem particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT IN 
And avoid the use of implicit join ... use explicit join eg: INNER JOIN

```
SELECT r.rom_ID
FROM rom r
WHERE r.rom_ID NOT IN (

SELECT r.rom_ID
FROM rom r
INNER JOIN  booking b  ON b.rom_ID = r.rom_ID 
and (
     '2018-05-08' BETWEEN b.ankomstdato AND b.utsjekkdato OR
         '2018-05-12' BETWEEN b.ankomstdato AND b.utsjekkdato OR 
         ('2018-05-08' <= b.ankomstdato AND  '2018-05-12' >= b.utsjekkdato
    ) ) )  AND r.romtype_ID = 2
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the query that you want is for a free room during a period of type 2.  That would look like:

```
SELECT r.rom_ID
FROM rom r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM booking b
                  WHERE b.utsjekkdato > '2018-05-08' AND
                        b.ankomstdato < '2018-05-12'
                 ) AND
      r.romtype_ID = 2
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that the strict inequalities could be `<=` and/or `>=` depending on what being available really means.